# testing liberty reserve shopping cart interface

Tags: php, payment-gateway

How can I test liberty reserve shopping cart interface (sci). They do not have a sandbox like paypal. I have already created php script for making payment. I think we need another liberty reserve account to test the payment. ie, one account for accepting payment and another for making payment. Is there any other way to test the script ?

Answer (score 0):

I have chat with their representative, They do not provide any test accounts. We need another liberty reserve account for testing.